# How to test USSD flows?

Tags: user-research, usability-testing, users

I'm working on some USSD (Unstructured Supplementary Service Data) flows that basically helps health workers in remote communities without internet access to collect basic data (height, age, weight) of the residents in that locality.

My question is this: how do I user test both the ease of use and also the wordings (local language translation) of the USSD flows?

Answer (score 1):

Travel to the remote locations and conduct User Testing in the field in conjunction with an interpreter. That is how you can obtain the best results. I have done that and learnt more than I expected.

Since you have made no mention on limitations such as budget or time, I have offered advice that yields the best results.